# Performance information unavailable while training MATLAB Neural Networks - always trains to maximum epoch

Tags: matlab, neural-network, training-data

I'm using the MATLAB neural network toolbox to solve a measurement/classification problem for a degree project, but I've been having a number of difficulties of which the latest I cannot figure out myself or from searching forums.

I have a fairly substantial dataset to train and test with (I am trying to measure ECG Q-T interval by feeding the network signals through a moving window) and so it would be useful for me to run the simulation in parallel on the cluster I've set up at home instead of using the toolbox GUI to 'design' and train as it's less configurable.

With the GUI and just a portion of my dataset (for time reasons) I achieve OK classification results and training stops somewhere around 180 epochs, but when I train an identical network (just a simple MATLAB patternnet) outside of the GUI using train() no performance data is available during training and training always continues until the epoch limit in both serial and parallel.

I have compared outputs and the network with the GUI (where training stopped automatically before maximum epoch) is considerably more effective. ALSO - running the script generated by the GUI for the good network yields the same training problems.

Clearly something isn't correctly configured if it works in the GUI but not in my 'environment, but I don't know what. Has anyone had any experience with this and know what it could be?